# Google Cloud App Engine app.yaml php72 issue with routing

Tags: php, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, app.yaml

I have a core php website and this is my current configuration of app.yaml

```
runtime: php72

handlers:
# Serve a directory as a static resource.
- url: /assets
  static_dir: assets

- url: /css
  static_dir: css

- url: /js
  static_dir: js

- url: /ckeditor
  static_dir: ckeditor

# Serve images as static resources.
- url: /(.+\.(gif|png|jpg))$
  static_files: \1
  upload: .+\.(gif|png|jpg)$

# add all script entries like this
- url: /login.php
  script: auto

# Serve your app through a front controller at index.php or public/index.php.
- url: .*
  script: auto
```

Issue with this configuration is that it keeps redirecting (302) to login page again and again.. and ending up with error *Too Many Redirects*.

What am I missing?

GAE Logs:

```
2019-01-18 17:10:07 default[20190118t223420]  "GET /login.php HTTP/1.1" 302
2019-01-18 17:10:10 default[20190118t223420]  "GET /login.php HTTP/1.1" 302
2019-01-18 17:10:13 default[20190118t223420]  "GET /login.php HTTP/1.1" 302
2019-01-18 17:10:16 default[20190118t223420]  "GET /login.php HTTP/1.1" 302
2019-01-18 17:10:19 default[20190118t223420]  "GET /login.php HTTP/1.1" 302
2019-01-18 17:10:22 default[20190118t223420]  "GET /login.php HTTP/1.1" 302
2019-01-18 17:10:25 default[20190118t223420]  "GET /login.php HTTP/1.1" 302
2019-01-18 17:32:26 default[20190118t225141]  "GET / HTTP/1.1" 302
2019-01-18 17:32:26 default[20190118t225141]  nginx: [warn] the "user" directive makes sense only if the master process runs with super-user privileges, ignored in /tmp/google-config/nginx.conf:3
2019-01-18 17:32:30 default[20190118t225141]  "GET /login.php HTTP/1.1" 302
2019-01-18 17:32:33 default[20190118t225141]  "GET /login.php HTTP/1.1" 302
2019-01-18 17:54:59 default[20190118t230733]  "GET / HTTP/1.1" 302
2019-01-18 17:55:00 default[20190118t230733]  nginx: [warn] the "user" directive makes sense only if the master process runs with super-user privileges, ignored in /tmp/google-config/nginx.conf:3
2019-01-18 17:55:02 default[20190118t230733]  "GET /login.php HTTP/1.1" 302
2019-01-18 17:55:05 default[20190118t230733]  "GET /login.php HTTP/1.1" 302
2019-01-18 17:55:07 default[20190118t230733]  "GET /login.php HTTP/1.1" 302
2019-01-18 17:55:09 default[20190118t230733]  "GET /login.php HTTP/1.1" 302
2019-01-18 17:55:11 default[20190118t230733]  "GET /login.php HTTP/1.1" 302
2019-01-18 18:17:29 default[20190118t230733]  "GET / HTTP/1.1" 302
2019-01-18 18:17:32 default[20190118t230733]  "GET /login.php HTTP/1.1" 302
2019-01-18 18:17:35 default[20190118t230733]  "GET /login.php HTTP/1.1" 302
2019-01-18 18:17:37 default[20190118t230733]  "GET /login.php HTTP/1.1" 302
2019-01-18 18:17:40 default[20190118t230733]  "GET /login.php HTTP/1.1" 302
```

Comment: Can you show the GAE logs for several consecutive such requests, preferably including the original request that starts such a looping sequence?

Comment: I have added what I could gather.. @DanCornilescu

Comment: Your `app.yaml` appears to be fine.  Can you post your `index.php`?

Comment: My guess is that the `script: auto` you have for `/login.php` is actually hitting some other script, not your `login.php` one and thus gets redirected again to `/login.php`. But I'm not certain - not a php user. I see in the code snippet at https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php7/configuring-your-app-with-app-yaml: `# Defaults to "serve index.php" and "serve public/index.php".`

Comment: @GAEfan I removed all rules except run time.. it still goes 302....

Comment: Also try to change from `script: auto` to `"script: login.php"` for your `url: /login.php`.

Comment: @MittulAtTechnoBrave tried it throws error lik script must be auto.

Comment: Finally I managed to resolve it. Please check my answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It turns out that php72 doesn't support script execution directly for standard environment. Everything needs to go through custom FrontController. So I created one FrontController which handles basically all routes. Below is the code I put in index.php. It will handle all specified routes.

```
switch (@parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])['path']) {
    case '/':
        require 'login.php';
        break;
    case '/product.php';
        require 'product.php';
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
```

You can find examples for php72 for custom FrontController and for different frameworks here. https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/php-docs-samples/tree/master/appengine

Thank you everyone for all your efforts. Hope this helps lost souls like me.

Comment: If anybody is coming here, and needs a little more context, I've got a gist just for that: https://gist.github.com/Mcgurk-Adam/c66b5c473e71d6e724b7e8e4329757f3

Answer (score 2):

Dynamic:

```
switch (@parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])['path']) 
{
    case @parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])['path']:
    $name_url_path = substr(@parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])['path'],1);
    $name_url_path = empty($name_url_path)?'home_page.php':$name_url_path;
    $name_url_path = ($name_url_path == 'index.php')?'home_page.php':$name_url_path;
    require $name_url_path;
    break;
    default:
    break;
}
```